# How to check if specified date contains in records or not

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I want something strange here. I've table names as `EMP_INFO` which contains few details of an employee (i.e. Name,Designation, JOIN_FROM, JOIN_TO). I am trying to figure out term for each employee on yearly basis. I've below types of data

```
EMP_ID   EMP_DESIG     JOIN_FROM    JOIN_TO                Query Result
  1      Supervisor    01-05-11     30-04-13               Should Display
  2      Supervisor    15-06-10     31-12-12               Should Display
  3      Jobar         01-01-12     31-12-13               Should Display
  4      SR Superior   01-12-11     31-12-15               Should Display
  5      Supervisor    01-05-11     31-12-13               Should Display
  6      Supervisor    01-05-11     31-12-13               Should Display
  7      Supervisor    01-05-11     31-12-13               Should Display
  8      Supervisor    01-02-12     15-06-13               Should Display
  9      SR Superior   16-03-10     18-11-11               Should Display
  10     SR Superior   16-06-05     18-11-11               Should Display
  11     Jobar         30-11-11     31-12-13               Should Display
  12     Superior      02-02-05     31-12-20               Should Display
  13     Jobar         30-11-11     31-12-13               Should Display
  14     Jobar         30-11-09     31-12-10               Should Not Display
```

Basically what i need is I have date range in my report and let's say From: "01-Jun-11" To "31-Dec-13". From above record set report should retrieve all records as all records contains this both dates.

I have tried by using BETWEEN syntax but i believe it will not work.

If anyone can help me in this than it would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.. And one more thing if this details is not enough to understand than let me know i will add more in details.

**Modified**
Query which I tried

```
SELECT EI.*     
FROM EMP_INFO EI,     
     (SELECT 
     TO_DATE('01-JUN-2011','DD-MON-YYYY') A,
     TO_DATE('31-DEC-2013','DD-MON-YYYY') B FROM DUAL) X   
WHERE   
(EI.JOIN_FROM IS NOT NULL AND EI.JOIN_TO IS NOT NULL)    
AND   (
           X.A BETWEEN EI.JOIN_FROM AND EI.JOIN_TO   
       AND X.B BETWEEN EI.JOIN_FROM AND EI.JOIN_TO   
       OR (EI.JOIN_FROM >= X.B   AND EI.JOIN_TO <=X.A)    )
```

**Modified** Added column (Query Result) on above table which contains result for each record.

Comment: Can you include the query you tried?

Comment: @AbhinavRanjan: Look added query which i tried

Comment: the table date columns are date types or varchar?

Comment: @AbhinavRanjan: Both date columns are under DATE datatype.

Comment: Currently i am using my phone so can't do much. I would suggest use date_format to covert your dates to the same format and then do the comparison.

Comment: BTW what was the output from your query?

Comment: @AbhinavRanjan: It is only returning 5,6 and 7th row as result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you simply want all records where the join time is in the given time range? That would be:

```
SELECT *     
FROM EMP_INFO
WHERE JOIN_FROM BETWEEN 
  TO_DATE('01-JUN-2011','DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') AND 
  TO_DATE('31-DEC-2013','DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')
AND JOIN_TO BETWEEN 
  TO_DATE('01-JUN-2011','DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') AND 
  TO_DATE('31-DEC-2013','DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN');
```

EDIT: Sorry, I got it now. You are looking for all time ranges that overlap with the given range. That would be: ranges that start before and end within, ranges that start before and end after, ranges that start within and end within and ranges that start within and end after. Another way to express this is: Either the given time range start is within the other time range or the other time range start is within the given time range. Here is the according statement:

```
SELECT *     
FROM EMP_INFO
WHERE JOIN_FROM BETWEEN 
  TO_DATE('01-JUN-2011','DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') AND 
  TO_DATE('31-DEC-2013','DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')
OR TO_DATE('01-JUN-2011','DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')
  BETWEEN JOIN_FROM AND JOIN_TO;
```

And here is the SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b58b3/3

Comment: Thanks for your response. But This query also will not work. If you see first record, there is "01-May-11" but since after that we will have all date (i.e. from "01-Jun-11" to "30-04-13". which are valid date for provided date range) which will come under our date range rit??? so that record should display in search result. Ideally all records should display which contains part of provided date.

Comment: Ah, I see. You don't want only records where their whole range is between the given Dates, but also those where part of their range is in there. So just replace AND JOIN_TO with OR JOIN_TO. That's it.

Comment: Let's assume in one the record if i have date like "JOIN_FROM" = "01-01-02" and JOIN_TO = "20-01-20". If you look into this date than this date contains years (i.e. 2011, 2012, 2013) correct???. So it should display as it is part of this range but in this case it will not display

Comment: No, I still don't understand. Either you want only complete ranges included, then you use above query with AND. Or you want also partly covered ranges, then you use the query with OR. Have you tried it with OR?

Comment: Yes i tried with OR but failed in one of the scenario. So I used ur query with some addition and i think it will work. And yes i need all records which comes under the range and partly covered range as well. Like this : If JOIN_FROM contains '01-Jun-12' than it should display in result and same case with JOIN_TO

Comment: Updated query result in question. Look on that once hope you will get idea for same.

Comment: I saw your edit. And this is exactly what you achieve with above query with OR instead of AND. #14 ends before the required period. Neither JOIN_FROM nor JOIN_TO is between the given dates, so the record is not shown. I see no reason to make further changes to the statement.

Comment: I know if i use OR instead of AND then #14 will not display but if you look at #12 it will also not display by using OR and hence i suggested the modified query.

Comment: Sorry I was either dumb or tired :-) I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to same format and compare. There may be a time component in the dates stored in database. Previous answer was wrong.

Comment: But as i mentioned in my question that i need those records which contains the specified date range. Let's take an example with 11th record. It has value JOIN_FROM = 30-11-11 and JOIN_TO = 31-12-13. Since this entire period (2011 to 2013) comes under selected range, it should display in result but query which i've written is not giving me proper result.

Comment: Then you should compare join_to between x.a and x.b.

Comment: Is that you what you wanted?

Comment: No dude and thanx for your help...I dont know i am providing u the understandable information to you or not. But still it will not work. Look above answer which I provided to "Thorsten Kettner"

Comment: For 11th case x.a is 01-05-11 so x.a is not between 30-11-11 and 30-12-13 so you will not get it in your result.